# What number follows the sequence?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

I was taking a job application exam online and encountered a pattern I couldn't solve.

? 26, 13.2, 3.6, 2, 1.2, ?

What number comes next? Answer choices were:

- 7.2
- 5.4
- 6.4
- 6.8
- 7
- 6.6

I guessed 6.6 due to the pattern right of the decimal, but I couldn't see any trend left of the decimal.

What number comes next?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is

> 6.8

Reason

> You start with 1.2 which is the least number and continue like this:
>  $(1.2*2)-0.4=2, (2*2)-0.4=3.6, (3.6*2)-0.4=6.8, (6.8*2)-0.4=13.2, (13.2*2)-0.4=26$

Comment: good finding, but in your case I would expect the " ?" between 13.2 and 3.6 and not at the end.

Comment: It might just be a "find the most fitting number"- question, disguised as a traditional number sequence

Answer (score 3):

Μy answer is   6

My reasoning is based on the following subtractions and additions.

```
 26-13.2=12.8              3.6+2+1.2+6=12.8

 26-13.2-3.6=9.2           2+1.2+6=9.2

 26-13.2-3.6-2=7.2         1.2+6=7.2


 26-13.2-3.6-2-1.2=6         =6


 26-13.2-3.6-2-1.2-6=0       =0
```

Comment: That seems rather plausible. Nice find. Unfortunately I can't confirm the correct answer, but I appreciate the replies in this thread and will help me to think about it going forward.

Comment: I don't see what is special here. It seems like you could produce the first line using any sequence of numbers (replacing 6 by the appropriate choice) After the first line, all you are doing is subtracting the same number from both equations.

Comment: I had to work with the given numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this pattern is too weird to be the actual answer, nevertheless it's a pattern.

The answer would be

> 7.2

Reason

> If you sum the digits of the numbers, you get the pattern:
>  Even Odd Odd Even Odd
>  So the next should give an odd sum of digits

> Then you notice that all the three "Odd" in the sequence have decimals and if you multiply the integer part by the decimal you obtain a number that is divisible by 2 just once (not divisible by 4)

> 7.2 is the only answer with a decimal part, whose sum of digits is odd and product of integer and decimal part is divisible by 2 only once.